# How to Optimize Code for an Informatics Competition Question?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner coder training for an informatics olympiad by attempting to solve some of the beginner problems they have on their website. My code of choice is python. One question that I am stuck on involves reading an input file where the first line has two integers separated by a space, representing the number of entries in a dictionary (each entry has a number and its translation (different number) beside it) and the number of lines (following the dictionary entries) of integers. I have to write a solution that translates these integers. For integers with no translation, 'C?' is used.

Input Sample

```
5 6
2 71
3 556
140 19
87 555
71 3
140
2
87
2
3
4
```

Output Sample

```
19
71
555
71
556
C?
```

My original solution was to search for each integer I needed to translate in the dictionary, and then append its translation to the output file.

```
input_file = open("dictin.txt", "r")
output_file = open("dictout.txt", "a")

input_file_list = input_file.readlines()
info = input_file_list[0].split()

dictionary = input_file_list[1:int(info[0]) + 1]
phrase = input_file_list[int(info[0]) + 1: len(input_file_list)]

for word in phrase:
    key_num = 0
    word_exists = False
    for key in dictionary:
        if int(key.split()[0]) == int(word):
            output_file.write(key.split()[1] + "\n")
            word_exists = True
            break
        else:
            key_num += 1
    if not word_exists:
        output_file.write("C?\n")
        word_exists = False

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

While this solution does work, it does not meet the 1 second time limit required of the problem, meaning that it is too inefficient. However, I'm unsure of how to make it run faster. I have tried to find a better way to find whether a word exists in the dictionary in the first place but this doesn't work due to how I parse the file. Is there possibly some syntax or maybe a module I could import (if necessary). Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The coding challenge is a red herring, IMHO. Anyhow, optimizing requires measuring improvements, so set up a benchmark. Also, if you don't know where you spend how much time, you can only guess which code to improve. Lastly, repeating things unnecessarily is a time killer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you continually interate through your input as strings, converting to `int` *every* time you access it.  This is a *huge* waste of time.  Instead, as the problem suggests, make a dictionary (Python `dict`) from the inputs.  If this is new to you, then work through a tutorial on dicts -- Stack Overflow is not the place to repeat existing tutorials.

You're losing time in iterating through the dict, just to find the key.  You can kill that loop.  Convert `word` to `int`, then

```
if word in dict:
```

Even better, you should use `get` for a lookup with a back-up value:

```
out_val = my_dict.get(word, 'C')
```

Then you write `out_val` to the output file.